# How do I use directed taunts?

Tags: smite

While exploring around the wiki I noticed in the voice sample section there is a "directed taunt" section for many of the gods.

[Example (scroll down)](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Athena_voicelines)

How do I activate these taunts?

EDIT: I noticed that Geb has a directed taunt at Nut, who isn't implemented into the game yet. That leads me to believe Directed taunts in general arent fully implemented? [Geb Voicelines](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Geb_voicelines?version=a832dca53c5fbaf5cc86c3de2255ef03)

Comment: Just a guess, but it likely has to do with proximity to those specific gods when you taunt. If I were going to SCIENCE this, that's where I'd start.

Comment: I would science this, but the chances of being matched up against a "tauntable" god is low. Knowing how to activate the taunts when I do meet them is preferred.

Comment: I think it's VET to taunt.

Comment: Doing the VET to taunt only activates the generic taunts (they are listed there as well), I was thinking maybe you would need to target the specific god and taunt them, but not sure.. hence question.

Comment: There is no special targeted taunt action. So it’s either VET or automatic. Potentially having to look at the target, be closest to it rather than others, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directed taunts appear to be used automatically without user input. If there's a way to manually use them, I'm unaware of it.

Athena has a directed taunt against Apollo ("HAH! You call that Singing?!"). In a recent Conquest match-up, Athena (played by me) automatically used this directed taunt while Apollo on the opposing team died in my vicinity. This appears to only happen if you have contributed to the kill via either an assist or killing blow.

As far as your question is concerned, it appears that the directed taunts are automatically fired during game-play if the situation warrants them.

Answer (score 0):

The direct taunt only activates when you either get a kill or assist on a god that is lore-tied to your own god that you are using.

i.e. When Thor kills Loki he uses a direct taunt.